# Test if an unevaluated promise exists

Tags: r

I has the following function:

```
f <- function(a, b=list()) {
  if(exists("b")) {
    if(exists("x",b)){
      a+b[["x"]]
    } else {
      a
    }
  } else {
    -a
  }
}
```

And it's work, except when I put a undefined value for `b`:

```
exists("tmp")
# [1] FALSE
f(a = 1, b=tmp)
# Error in exists("x", b) : object 'tmp' not found
```

Is there a function to check if the promise value exists inside my function `f`?

Comment: In my example, `missing(b)` is `False`, has there is a `b = tmp` as argument for the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this.

```
f <- function(a, b=list()) {
  tryCatch(force(b), error=function(e) b<<-NULL)
  if(!is.null(b)) {
    if(exists("x",b)){
      a+b[["x"]]
    } else {
      a
    }
  } else {
    -a
  }
}

f(5, tmp)
# [1] -5
f(5, list(x=3))
# [1] 8
f(5, list(z=3))
# [1] 5
```

Here we force evaluation of the parameter to see if it exists or resolves to something within a `tryCatch()` expression to handle the case where the variable does not exist. If it doesn't exist, we set it to NULL to make the rest of the function easier to work with.